# google VR Android Studio - unable to build project

Tags: android, android-studio, google-vr

I'm very new in android development. I'm trying to do a simple tutorial on **google VR** using **Android Studio**. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/vr_view_app_101/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0 
Here I have to clone a project from git, then clone another project which has to be included in the main project. When I edit the **build.gradle** file I get this error: 
**Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 Cannot evaluate module common : Configuration with name 'default' not found.**. I moved the project directory to the Android Studio's home directory but this did not solved my problem. 
This is my gradle file (settings.gradle)

```
include ':app'

include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:audio'  include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:base'  include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:common' include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:commonwidget'  include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:panowidget'  include ':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:videowidget'
```

and here is my build.gradle file (Module.app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.devrel.vrviewapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:common')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:commonwidget')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:panowidget')
}
```

and here is my project structure with the error
[image]

Comment: This problem seems unrelated to git.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the tag.